# Trying to get property of non object errors

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting a few trying to get property of non object errors. with the array that I have created. I created the array and am foreaching it out and by the looks of my object array those properties do exist.

I am getting the errors in this area:

```
// Separates each of the last 5 pesonal messages
foreach ($last_5_personal_messages AS $message)
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<span class="icon avatar"><img src="'.$message->sender_avatar.'" alt="" /></span>';
    echo '<span class="name"><a href="'.$site_url.'/personalmessages/viewmessage/'.$message->message_id.'"><strong>'.$message->sender_name.'</strong></a><span class="time">'.$message->datetime_sent.' ago</span></span>';
    echo '<span class="msg">'.$message->subject.'</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>


Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message_id] => 1
        [subject] => Test Message
        [datetime_sent] => 2 weeks
        [attachments] => 
        [priority] => 0
        [message_content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        [message_read] => 0
        [is_favorite] => 0
        [sender_name] => Mike Scott
        [sender_email_address] => myemail@myemail.com
        [sender_avatar] => http://dev.myserver.com/assets/themes/supr/images/avatars/avatar5.jpg
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message_id] => 2
        [subject] => Testing PM Message
        [datetime_sent] => 3 weeks
        [attachments] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [file_name] => file1.jpg
                        [is_file] => 1
                        [file_size] => 7.01 KB
                        [file_location] => assets/downloads/file1.jpg
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [file_name] => file2.jpg
                        [is_file] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [file_name] => file3.jpg
                        [is_file] => 
                    )

            )

        [priority] => 0
        [message_content] => This is jsut a test of the personal message system!
        [message_read] => 0
        [is_favorite] => 0
        [sender_name] => Kevin Scott
        [sender_email_address] => myemail@server.com
        [sender_avatar] => http://dev.myserver.com/assets/themes/supr/images/avatars/avatar5.jpg
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message_id] => 3
        [subject] => Testing Whatever
        [datetime_sent] => 1 week
        [attachments] => 
        [priority] => 0
        [message_content] => Testing Message Content
        [message_read] => 0
        [is_favorite] => 0
        [sender_name] => Frank Scott
        [sender_email_address] => frankscott@testemail.com
        [sender_avatar] => http://dev.myserver.com/assets/themes/supr/images/avatars/avatar.jpg
    )

[total_unread_messages] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GBD is right, it's because the `total_unread_messages` key does not contain an object as its value, so you get this warning.

You can also iterate over that array manually, using the information within `total_unread_messages` to your advantage, if you don't want to have that `if( is_object())` check on every loop iteration. Something like this should work:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $last_5_personal_messages['total_unread_messages'] && $i < 5; $i++) {
    $message = $last_5_personal_messages[$i];
     echo '<li>';
     // ....
}
```

Or you can [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) that value before you iterate (and optionally put it back when you're done):

```
unset( $last_5_personal_messages['total_unread_messages']);
foreach( $last_5_personal_messages as $message) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Only one problem with this though. The total unread messages key is a key that is more than just the last 5 message. Should I just take that key out and then pass the value a different way?

Comment: So if it's bigger than `5`, break out of the loop after 5 iterations have gone through - I've edited my answer to stop the loop if there are more than 5 messages.

Comment: @user1724167 it's fine.. i knew problem but didn't able to give better solution so which is given by nickb :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have key "total_unread_messages" in array which doesn't have object as value so skip that value while foreach

```
foreach ($last_5_personal_messages AS $message)
{
    if(!is_object($message)){
      continue;
    }
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<span class="icon avatar"><img src="'.$message->sender_avatar.'" alt="" /></span>';
    echo '<span class="name"><a href="'.$site_url.'/personalmessages/viewmessage/'.$message->message_id.'"><strong>'.$message->sender_name.'</strong></a><span class="time">'.$message->datetime_sent.' ago</span></span>';
    echo '<span class="msg">'.$message->subject.'</span>';
    echo '</li>';

}
```

Another way

```
for($i=0;$i<$last_5_personal_messages['total_unread_messages'];$i++)
{
   $message = $last_5_personal_messages[$i];

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<span class="icon avatar"><img src="'.$message->sender_avatar.'" alt="" /></span>';
    echo '<span class="name"><a href="'.$site_url.'/personalmessages/viewmessage/'.$message->message_id.'"><strong>'.$message->sender_name.'</strong></a><span class="time">'.$message->datetime_sent.' ago</span></span>';
    echo '<span class="msg">'.$message->subject.'</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, however, is there a better way I should add that value to the array so that I don't have to worry about doing that.